# Как найти ближайшее значение(ключ) к заданому из словаря вверх?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, поиск, словари

Есть вот такой словарь:

```
dict = {9: ('9',), 8: ('8',), 7: ('7',), 18: ('9', '9'), 17: ('9', '8'), 16: ('9', '7'), 15: ('8', '7'), 14: ('7', '7'), 26: ('9', '9', '8'), 25: ('9', '9', '7'), 24: ('9', '8', '7'), 23: ('9', '7', '7'), 22: ('8', '7', '7'), 33: ('9', '9', '8', '7'), 32: ('9', '9', '7', '7'), 31: ('9', '8', '7', '7'), 40: ('9', '9', '8', '7', '7')}
```

Как мне найти допустим ближайший ключ к 27?

Есть вот такой алгоритм но в данном случае он выводит 26(ближайшее значение вниз), а должен 31.

```
print(min(diction, key=lambda a:abs(a-27)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [77]: import math

In [78]: min(d, key=lambda a: a-27 if a>=27 else math.inf)
Out[78]: 31
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но нужно поставить >=